# Can Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services corrupt or interfere with a (non-light) Active Directory installation on the same network?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm a programmer with a limited understanding of Active Directory. I once asked the IT manager if I could install Active Directory on my development computer and he told me definitely not as it would conflict with the companies full blown Active Directory installation.

**Question**

Will installing and using Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services corrupt or interfere with a (non-lightweight) Active Directory installation on the same network?

Comment: Define interfere.  As a single source of account authority, absolutely.  It's vey rare that a new app would need its own directory instead of an attribute store.

Comment: I'm mainly worried that Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services will attempt to synchronize with the blown Active Directory installation. But my understanding of Active Directory is very limited so there could be other ways it would interfere that I haven't thought of.

Comment: You could configure it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will be no inteference. ADLDS is the Microsoft version of a LDAP-directory. There is no default connectivity to your companys ActiveDirectory that is containig all your companys user abd computer accounts.